# HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found in Mvc 6 Asp.net 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm using mvc beta6 and i want to have dynamic controller.
Right now i have created only two controller Home and Dynamic.
so default routing is controller/action and which was running fine till mvc 5
even we enter xyz/someaction in browser url.
But in case of mvc 6 it won't fire defaultcontroller factory and gives http error 404.because of that im not able to route to dynamic controller as user type in browser.
this is my start up code..

```
     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
            {

                //app.UseMvc();
                //// app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
                app.UseMvc(routes =>
                {
                    ///  routes.MapRoute("areaRoute", "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}");
                    routes.MapRoute("defaultRoute",
                        "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
                });
}
```

I think routing is only registered for actual controller existed in app during compilation time.if i'm wrong then please tell me about the dynamic routing.

Comment: can this article be of any help? http://forums.asp.net/t/2013033.aspx?Manually+instantiate+a+Controller+in+MVC+6+alpha4

Answer (score 0):

I've got the solution for my problem.The way of finding controller in mvc6 is very different from its previous versions.In mvc 6 all the controller types are discovered during compile time and cached through the DI framework and routing are registered to only those cached controller.So system doesnot invoke any factory methods unless it finds the requested controller. :)
That's it!
ps:thanks for everyone who really gave their valuable times.

Answer (score -2):

i think you should try in following manner

```
              routes.MapRoute(
              name: "default",
              template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
              defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

You can also go with articles on my blog with ["Routing in MVC"](http://www.dotnet-stuff.com/search?q=Routing%20in%20mvc)

Comment: That is exactly what OP is already using (apart from the route name, which is irrelevant, and the named parameters, which are not required). Don't spam your blog.

Comment: I don't think he has issues with regular routing and he said it worked fine on MVC5. They problem is MVC 6 and news it introduced, especially in his special case.

Comment: Here i have added extra attribute template:"{controller}/{action}/{id?}", I am using in beta6 and it is working.

Comment: you didn't add the extra attribute, you just named the parameter that you are sending, which doesn't change anything in practice